# What event before new Scene is loaded ?

Tags: unity

Unity3d: I know exist OnApplicationQuit called before the application is ended.

But, does exists an event that is called before a new scene is loaded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, it's `SceneManager.activeSceneChanged`, it's defined as follows:

```cs
public static event UnityAction<Scene, Scene> activeSceneChanged;
```

The first argument is the current scene, the second argument is the new scene.

There's a page in the documentation with an actual usage example:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-activeSceneChanged.html

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for `SceneManager.sceneUnloaded` to get a notification when a scene has unloaded (or `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` to get a notification when a scene has loaded). See [Unity's documentation on SceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html).

Note that `OnLevelWasLoaded` is deprecated (marked as Obsolete) as of Unity 5.4. @Chris' answer is still supported, but it's preferable to use `SceneManager`. As that answer points out, keep in mind the [Execution Order of Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

See the example code in [SceneManager.sceneUnloaded documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneUnloaded.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoaded1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneUnloaded += OnSceneUnloaded;
        Debug.Log("Start: SceneLoaded1");
    }

    private void OnSceneUnloaded(Scene current)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneUnloaded: " + current);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Quitting Scene1");
            ChangeScene();
        }
    }

    void ChangeScene()
    {
        Debug.Log("Changing to Scene2");

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDestroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize OnLevelWasLoaded had been deprecated. Good to know!